# Was there any information on the Angels before the Clone Wars TV series?

Tags: star-wars

In Star Wars Episode I: The Phantom Menace, Anakin briefly mentions a race of people called the Angels, with no information other than their name, homeworld and supposed beauty.

Since then, however, a few Angels have appeared in the tv series, but this debuted much later.

So, was there any information at all on the Angels before their appearance in the tv show? Information from interviews with George and other non-universe sources are fine too.

I'm just wondering if they were ever planned to appear, or just something invented surperficially as a throw away line.

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Diathim#cite_note-Moon-0

Answer (score 4):

Between the release of [The Phantom Menance](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_I_The_Phantom_Menace) on May 19,1999 and Star Wars: The Clone Wars S01E18: [Mystery of a Thousands Moons](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mystery_of_a_Thousand_Moons) on February 13, 2009 the [Angels](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Diathim) were referenced in the following works

- [Star Wars Episode I Journal: Anakin Skywalker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I_Journal:_Anakin_Skywalker) (book 1999)
- [Star Wars: Knights of the Old Republic II: The Sith Lords](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_II:_The_Sith_Lords) (game 2004)
- [Geonosis and the Outer Rim Worlds](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Geonosis_and_the_Outer_Rim_Worlds) (book 2004)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm actually asking for any information before the tv series, that wasn't in the movie.

Comment: @Recelica - So you mean AFTER the movie but BEFORE the show? And are you looking for Canon only answers? Or Legends too?

Comment: Yes. Any information at all, even brief mentions of any kind.

Comment: I've downvoted. This answer doesn't address the question asked.

Comment: The KOTOR II reference to angels is an easter egg, and is almost certainly not canon. If you beat the game a couple of times, then play as a female, the first time you meet Atton, he'll say "Are you an angel? ...oh, that one's terrible. I hope some kid doesn't start using that." He then goes on to explain that he was originally going to be the protagonist of one of the *Jedi Knight* video games, but was placed in this one at the last minute..

Comment: @Thunderforge - Interesting. I never played the game so I didn't know. Technically it counts as a brief mention, so I'll leave it in my answer.